# Performance, apc define constants or apc fetch on language file

Tags: php, cakephp, apc

Today i have a new very weird question. I am trying to find a way to cache language pot files.

The standard way that CakePHP does this is it parses the file into an array and then returns the key value pair. I am looking at increasing the performance for this due to the file growing exponentially

I have four solutions for this but i don't know which of them will be easily maintainable and supply the fastest performance.

Option 1: Use CakePHP's standard method for translations but just split the files up a little bit and use the __d() function

Option 2: Use a class i wrote to parse the contents of all the langauge files and cache them using apc. Then retrieve the translation via apc_fetch

Option 3: Serialize the translation array using either serialize or json_encode (which ever works the fastest) and defining it using apc_define_contants

Option 4: Use apc_define_contants to define every key in the translation file as a contant with its value

I am stuck on this and i don't know what will be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you to some other possible solutions:

1. Cache them in memcache      - nice if you have some (enough) RAM
2. Cache them in [fatcache](https://github.com/twitter/fatcache) - a nice one if you have SSDs on your server
3. Serve them from [Redis](http://redis.io/)  - Since Redis is a very fast key-value store you should be able to move all your transalations to it, or just parse the `.po/.pot` files and "cache" them
   in redis. However with these approaches you will have to see how exactly to handle the cache and where to attach/retrieve it. There are a [`RedisEngine`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-RedisEngine.html) and [`MemcacheEngine`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-MemcacheEngine.html) in CakePHP.

Maybe your best solution would be some in-memory cache, like memcache.

Comment: What is the advantage in using memcache over APC?

Comment: I am not saying that your answer is wrong. I have upvoted for that reason. But i cannot move away from APC, due to the rest of our systems all use APC. I ran some tests as well but not nearly done with what i need

Comment: @symcbean no real advantage - just pointed out an alternative.